# SDL boilerplate

Tags: c++, exception, sdl

The SDL code example on the [`SDL_Init`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Init) page seems to be overly verbose, creating an exception class entirely for `SDL_Init`. I wanted to tone it down a bit by making everything `std::runtime_error`s.

1. Does it make sense to have global variables and a cleanup function?
2. Is it necessary to check if `win` is a valid pointer before calling `SDL_DestroyWindow`?
3. Is `SDL_GLContext` a `typedef` for a pointer? If so, should I not pass it by reference?

```
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_opengl.h>

#include <iostream>

void DestroyAndQuit(SDL_Window* win, SDL_Renderer* ren, SDL_GLContext& con)
{
  if (ren)
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
  if (win)
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
  if (con)
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(con);
  SDL_Quit();
}

SDL_Window* win = nullptr;
SDL_Renderer* ren = nullptr;
SDL_GLContext con;

int main(int argc, char **argv) try {
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
    throw std::runtime_error("SDL_Init failed.");
  }

  win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello, world!", 0, 0, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
  if (!win) {
    throw std::runtime_error("SDL_CreateWindow failed.");
  }

  ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
  if (!ren) {
    throw std::runtime_error("SDL_CreateRenderer failed.");
  }

  con = SDL_GL_CreateContext(win);
  if (!con) {
    throw std::runtime_error("SDL_GL_CreateContext failed.");
  }

  SDL_RenderClear(ren);
  SDL_RenderPresent(ren);

  glClearColor(0, 1, 1, 1);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  SDL_GL_SwapWindow(win);

  SDL_Delay(2000);

  DestroyAndQuit(win, ren, con);

  return 0;
 } catch(std::exception& ex) {
  std::cerr << ex.what() << ": " << SDL_GetError() << "\n";
  DestroyAndQuit(win, ren, con);
  return 1;
 }
```

Comment: Putting the catch outside the body is extremely rare. You will confuse people by doing that. Also the catch happens after main has exited so the return is not doing what you think. To actually return one you must move the try/catch into the body of main and do the return from inside the body.